# How to apply to one set of columns in a dataframe with multi-index columns

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, addition, multi-index

I have a dataframe with multi-index column as you see below, and what I am trying to do is for each user and for m1 and m2, I need to get the value for today+0.25*value for yesterday.

```
               m1              m2  
day           yesterday today yesterday today
user                                      
id1           5         6     7         8
id2           3         4     9         10
```

I have tried the following, but I get NA values in all "today" columns:

```
df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='today'] = 
df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='yesterday'] *0.25 +
 df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='today']
```

My search on other stackoverflow posts has led me to possible answer of grouping by level = 0, but I don't know how to go from there and how to apply a function to the result of the group by. 
Or perhaps that is not the right way to approach this?

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(...)
```

Firstly, what I need to get to is :

```
               m1                      m2  
day           yesterday today          yesterday today
user                                      
id1               5     6+0.25*5       7         8+0.25*7
id2               3     4+0.25*3       9         10+0.25*9
```

Ultimately, I need to get to :

```
user           m1              m2             
id1            6+0.25*5        8+0.25*7
id2            4+0.25*3        10+0.25*9
```

p.s. this is my first time asking question on StackOverflow, I did my best ! but please let me know if I need to modify my question to follow the guidelines. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for selecting, so is possible add `DataFrame`s together with multiple by constant.

Advantage of function is removed top levels (default value `drop_level=True`) - so working with no `MultiIndex` in output `DataFrame`s.

```
print (df.xs('today', axis=1, level=1))
     m1  m2
id1   6   8
id2   4  10

print (df.xs('yesterday', axis=1, level=1))
     m1  m2
id1   5   7
id2   3   9

df1 = df.xs('today', axis=1, level=1) + 0.25 *df.xs('yesterday', axis=1, level=1)
print (df1)
       m1     m2
id1  7.25   9.75
id2  4.75  12.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it!!!

```
def func(df):
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
    return(df['today']+0.25*df['yesterday'])
```

and then:

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(func)
```